# Yii: include form inside form

Tags: yii, renderpartial

There's a way to include form inside another form using the same action?
I tried with renderPartial but doesn't work.
eg:

> $this->renderPartial('//utente/_form', array('model'=>new User,
>   'condition'=>$condition, 'form' => $form, 'rule' => '3'), false,
>   true);

Comment: what is the error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use renderPartial(with return=true) to render result of first for in temporal variable.
2. Use the variable in second view.

[See CController renderPartial() for details](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.0/CController#renderPartial-detail)

```
$form1 = $this->renderPartial('firstView', $data1, true);

$this->renderPartial(
    '//utente/_form',
    array(
        'model'=>new User,
        'condition'=>$condition,
        'form' => $form,
        'rule' => '3',
        'form1' => $form1
    ),
    false,
    true
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Form inside another form doesn't work in HTML! You can't do this:

> ```
> <form ...>
>       ...
>       <form ...>
>           ...
>       </form>
> </form>
> ```